# HorizontalCollectionView Content width and spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

How can I make my horizontal collection view labels width to wrap the content width of the label and make them have equal spacing between each of them? Currently I have the collection view cell width as 100. If I increase the width to fit other labels, the shorter labels have more spacing between them. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the width of the label text first with the font associated with the text.

```
extension String {
    func size(with font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
        let fontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttribute)
        return size
    }
}
```

Return the calculated width along with collectionView height in `collectionView(_, collectionViewLayout:_, sizeForItemAt)`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let newWidth = titles[indexPath.row].size(with: labelFont!).width + 10 //Added 10 to make the label visibility very clear
    return CGSize(width: newWidth, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
}
```

**Entire source code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!

    let labelFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 18)
    let titles = ["Hi", "Hello", "HorizontalCollectionView", "VerticalCollectionView"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        collection.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 68/255, green: 143/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        collection.register(UINib.init(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCollectionViewCell")
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return titles.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 10 // Adjust the inter item space based on the requirement.
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let newWidth = titles[indexPath.row].size(with: labelFont!).width + 10 //Added 10 to make the label visibility very clear
    return CGSize(width: newWidth, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.font = labelFont!
        return cell
    }
}

extension String {
    func size(with font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
        let fontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttribute)
        return size
    }
}
```

**Another Solution:**

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collView: UICollectionView!


    var tasksArray = ["To Do", "SHOPPING","WORK"]
    var selectedIndex = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        let layout = collView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 170, height: 50)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasksArray.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.lblName.text = tasksArray[indexPath.row]
        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
        else
        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        self.collView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**Cell.swift**

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2
    }

    override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
        var frame = layoutAttributes.frame
        frame.size.width = ceil(size.width)
        layoutAttributes.frame = frame
        return layoutAttributes
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually calculate the width of each cell. To calculate the width, you actually calculate the width of the text residing in that cell.

use following

```
 boundingRect(with:options:attributes:context:)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrect

to calculate the width of a given string. So after calculating the returning the size the cell should be wrapping the text.

Now come the second part, equal spacing between items. use `interItemSpacing` to define the spacing between each cell.