# How to make UICollectioncell width dynamic according to text

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, uicollectionview

Guys I want to change the size of the cell like this [image]

Auto adjusting to the text. what I am able to achieve is
[image]

I have tried to search but not able to find out the solution. How can I make it dynamic to text.
The tags are coming from a model class and the colour and background is changing from custom class for the cell.

Comment: Calculate the width of the UILabel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527494/how-to-calculate-uilabel-width-based-on-text-length

And then implement  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize  of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Answer (score 1):

Its explained in the answer below.

[HorizontalCollectionView Content width and spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53193629/horizontalcollectionview-content-width-and-spacing/53194797#531947)

Calculate size of string with associate font.

```
extension String {
    func size(with font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
        let fontAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttribute)
        return size
    }
}
```

Return the calculated width along with collectionView height in `collectionView(_, collectionViewLayout:_, sizeForItemAt)`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let newWidth = titles[indexPath.row].size(with: labelFont!).width + 10 //Added 10 to make the label visibility very clear
    return CGSize(width: newWidth, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
}
```

Comment: I implemented this code but somehow this block is not getting executed. Its not going only to this block of code. any idea why?

Comment: Thanks brother its been done I was missing the flowdelegate.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below:-

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle(?*self.arr[indexPath.row].name, for: .normal)
        let btnWidth =  ?*btn.intrinsicContentSize.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32 ? ?*btn.intrinsicContentSize.width - 32 : ?*btn.intrinsicContentSize.width
        return CGSize(width: (?*btnWidth), height: 48)
    }
```

You can modify it according to your requirement. Comment if you need any help in this.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Its taking the largest text available and giving the width according to that. Not adjusting to every particular cell text. Any idea why?

Comment: Thanks brother for your help. I solved it actually I was missing the flow delegate.